# How To Make My Map Fit the Whole Screen in Layout view

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cartography

This is my page and print setup 
[image: this is my page and print set up]

This is my layout view 
[image]

I want to make my layout view bigger. How can I expand it to the full extent. Sorry if this seems like a stupid question but I've tried everything and it doesn't work.

Comment: you don't describe if you want to zoom in or print bigger.the answer tells both.

Comment: Have you tried adding the 'Layout' toolbar or right clicking and pressing the 'Zoom Whole Page' button.

Comment: I guess my question is how do I expand the margins of the map. I've changed the width and height but the size of the margins just seem to stay the same

Comment: It was the layout toolbar I had to install it and zoom in more. Thanks guys!

Comment: You seem to be asking two questions.  Above you want the margin to extend to the edge of the maps,  do that in layout view by right clicking, then disbtributing, then fit to margins.  Alternatively you can drag the blue lines to the edge of margins.  For the second part, which you seem to indicate below, is you want layout view to be larger,  simply use the mouse wheel to zoom in and out but scrolling up and down with it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I dont know which of these two you meant, To make the actual layout view map larger on your screen use your mousewheel (also right click and zoom to whole page, but this may not zoom in as much as you want.) Or use the layout toolbar and the layout zoom tools...
[image: Layout]

To make the map fit the actual extent of the page right click on the map, then distribute, then fit to margins

[image]

Comment: yes the layout toolbar worked, I'm such an idiot. Thank You!

Comment: Excellent glad we could help!  You may want to delete the answer you posted and put it in the comments since its not really an answer.  If you cant do that I bet the mods will when they get a chance.